# material-ui fab card in reactJS

Tags: material-ui, floating-action-button

I have a FAB button on my site, which shows play and pause button, but what I would like to do it replace that with a fab media card. So it shows now playing information as well, I am sure it was never designed for something like this, but I would like if possible to show the now playing information to our listeners.

This is what it currently looks like:

[image]

The Fab code

```
<Fab aria-label='test' className={classes.fab}>


            <i className='large material-icons' style={fabIcon} onClick={handleClick}>
            { icon ? 'play_circle_outline' : 'pause_circle_outline'}</i>
          </Fab>
```

the component I want to show inside the fab area is

```
<MediaControlCard />
```

Comment: Why don't you just absolutely position a card at the bottom right of the screen, and inside that, place a FAB?

Comment: @ninjaPixel because I was trying to do it the Google Correct way